# Push Data Into An Objects Array With Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Say I had the following:

```
.controller("chatCtrl", function($scope, $timeout, $rootScope) {
  $scope.chats = [{
    id: 1,
    username: "Aname",
    avatar: "imgsrc",
    messages: [
      "Hello",
      "World"
    ]
  }];
```

How would I go about pushing data from a form into the messages array? I have a form setup as so:

```
%form{"ng-submit" => "add()"}
%input{:type => "text", :placeholder => "Enter a message", "ng-model" => "text"}
%input{:type => "submit", :value => "Send"}
```

and my Angular as so:

```
$scope.text = '';
$scope.messages = [];

$scope.add = function() {
  if($scope.text) {
    $scope.messages.push(this.text);
    $scope.text = '';
    console.log($scope.messages);
  }
}
```

Now of course this works because it is pushing it to the $scope.messages array I just defined, but I need to submit it to the $scope.chats messages array.

Comment: @drakkin Hey guys! Yes you would think so right? I have tried it previously but I get this error - 'Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$scope.chats.messages.push')

Comment: Does `$scope.chats[0].messages.push` work?

Comment: @Drakkin Hey Drakking yes it is

Comment: @PatrickEvans That's correct but the output is undefined

Comment: @SlashmanX It doesn't I tried adding the index but it's outputted as undefined D:

Comment: it is not     $scope.messages.push(this.text); but     $scope.messages.push($scope.text);

Comment: @PatrickEvans suggestion worked! The reason it was undefined was because I didn't console it out correctly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
$scope.text= '';

$scope.add = function() {
   $scope.chats[0].messages.push($scope.text);
};
```

Comment: Thank you - Patrick Evans suggested the index within the array & that worked great. Thank you!